# JavaScript: Convert nested json to csv

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I have a nested json which I want to convert in csv using javascript and download it.

Below are the json details:

```
{
  "table_1" : [
    {
      "a": "apple",
      "b": "ball"
    },
    {
      "a": "alpha",
      "b": "beta"
    }
    ],
    "table_2" : [
      {
        "m" : "mango",
        "n" : 1,
        "o" : "orange"
      },
      {
        "m" : "melon",
        "n" : 2,
        "o" : "olive"
      },
      {
        "m" : "mulberry",
        "n" : 3,
        "o" : "onion"
      }
      ]
}
```

And desired CSV is something like this:

[image]

Now, please let me know, how I can do that is JS.
**I specifically looking for with multiple table like output in one csv file. As soon on the picture.**

***Please note,

> the structure of the 2 table is different
>
> 1st ong has 2 column naming a,b
>
> &
>
> 2nd one 3 columns naming m,n,o

---

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for your advice, but I have done my research, and couldn't find any direction, that's why, I posted that question. If you feel like it's not complete or inappropriate or irrelevant please let me know, I will try to phase the question with more possible information,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `npm` module https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv

`$ npm install json2csv --save`

```
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'];

try {
  var result = json2csv({ data: myData, fields: fields });
  console.log(result);
} catch (err) {
  // Errors are thrown for bad options, or if the data is empty and no fields are provided.
  // Be sure to provide fields if it is possible that your data array will be empty.
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: can we create multiple tables with json2csv?

Comment: @anij why you want append two tables to one table? it's stupid.
please create 2 another csv tables

Comment: @anij if you want append second table to first you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv#appending-to-existing-csv

Comment: @alex dykyi both this table i want in single csv file. And down want to append the 2 tables 1 want 2 separate tables but in same page. Is it possible?

Comment: @anij yes its possible 
if you want append second table to first you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv#appending-to-existing-csv

Comment: @alex i saw the append example, but there table are in same structure, but here, my 2nd table structure is different.

Comment: @alex it's writen over there "additional rows with the same columns". but mine 2 table structures are different.

Comment: @anij you can use this lib for appending another table https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-write-stream#default-options

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did it like this:

**code:**

```
    var data = {
            "table_1" : [
              {
                "a": "apple",
                "b": "ball"
              },
              {
                "a": "alpha",
                "b": "beta"
              }
              ],
              "table_2" : [
                {
                  "m" : "mango",
                  "n" : 1,
                  "o" : "orange"
                },
                {
                  "m" : "melon",
                  "n" : 2,
                  "o" : "olive"
                },
                {
                  "m" : "mulberry",
                  "n" : 3,
                  "o" : "onion"
                }
                ]
          };

    var csvData = [""];
    csvData.push(["+++++++++++++++++++++++"]);
    csvData.push(["SAMPLE REPORT"]);
    csvData.push(["+++++++++++++++++++++++"]);
    csvData.push([""]);
    csvData.push(["TABLE 1"]);
    csvData.push(["========="]);
    csvData.push(["a","b"]);
    data.table_1.forEach(function(record){
      csvData.push(record);
    });
    csvData.push(["----------------------------------------------------------"]);
    csvData.push([""]);
    csvData.push(["TABLE 2"]);
    csvData.push(["========="]);
    csvData.push(["m","n","o"]);
    data.table_2.forEach(function(record){
      csvData.push(record);
    });

    util.JSONToCSVConvertor(util.copy(csvData), "Sample Report", true);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Please, let me know if any other optimized way is there.

Answer (score -1):

A simple iteration loop on the 1st level and another iteration loop on the inside, if the 1st iteration on the inside loop - add columns names.